# Continuous map $f:S^5 \to \mathbb{C}P^2$ with $f(x)\perp f(-x) $

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Is  there  a  continuous  map $f:S^5 \to  \mathbb{C}P^2$  such that $\forall x \in S^5,\; f(x)\perp f(-x) $?

The  motivation is  mentioned here

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278828/a-question-motivated-by-a-non-homological-proof-of-the-3-dim-borsuk-ulam-theor